# How do I update a SQL table on all clients when i update the server?

Tags: mysql, publish-subscribe

I have a web server with a SQL DB and a specific table. This table also exists on all clients. How do I update this on all clients when I update the table on the server.

Comment: With implementing observer observable design pattern.

Comment: Do you mean like in this tutorial? :https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm

Comment: Is it a postgresql DB? If not, what DB is it?

Comment: Im using a MySQL DB.

Comment: @brondy yes, you can do it with plsql